# When did Naruto learn how to generate a Rasengan unassisted?

Tags: naruto

Jiraiya, Minato, and Kakashi each could generate and maintain a Rasengan using only one hand. When Naruto first learned the technique, he needed shadow clones to help him.

When did Naruto learn how to generate and maintain a Rasengan without the aid of shadow clones or chakra arms?

Comment: I think you should add word like *perfect or stable of complete Rasengan*. He was able to generate Rasengan after training with Jiraya but took long time and was not stable and fade away.

Comment: [While Naruto had invented new ways to use a Rasengan and its variants, he still used shadow clones, and later chakra arms, to create them. By the end of the Fourth Shinobi World War, Naruto had become skilled enough to use the technique unassisted, with his regular Rasengan expanding to the size of a Big Ball Rasengan.](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Rasengan) so the answer is at the end of the Fourth Shinobi World War.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first time Naruto used Rasengan without clones or chakra hands is in Naruto episode 134 at around 8:20 ([YouTube video](https://youtu.be/pb-6C9D05AM?t=1075)). He first used Rasengan with only one hand although he is assisted by Six-Tails chakra.

Comment: Arguably, this is still assisted by Kurama, as even after the timeskip, he still uses clones, even into his fight with Pein. it's not until Kyubbi Chakra cloak that he could do it with one had (or chakra hand) which was shown in his fight with Obito i believe, but its Sage of Six paths naruto that could do Rasen shuriken with one hand (though he may have had help from the tailed beasts) its almost arguable he never learned how to do so.

Answer (score 1):

When Naruto and Sasuke were fighting in episode 134, Sasuke let his curse mark's power activate. He knew that the power would soon eat away his body, so he planned to finish off Naruto with a Chidori. However, when the Nine-Tails' cloak took over Naruto's body, he didn't need a clone to make a Rasengan. So, to counter Sasuke's Chidori, Naruto made a Rasengan with a single hand for the first time. Later on, Naruto never really noticed how amazing that was, or how he still had to use shadow clones for a while.

Answer (score 1):

In the Fourth Shinobi Great War, after Sasuke and Naruto receive half the Sage of Six Paths Chakra, Naruto has the ability to maintain a perfect Sage Mode, and directly after that, he made a Lava Style: Rasenshuriken with one hand using Four-Tails Chakra and cut Madara in half with it. So he used the sage art Lava Style: Rasenshuriken first with one hand. So it is evident he could make the Rasengan with one hand after gaining the Six Paths power.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it was after Naruto got half of the Sage of Six Path Chakra, mainly because in part one (ep. 135), he had the cloak of the Nine-Tails to help him, so he wasn't conscious of it. I think he was conscious of it when he fought Sasuke because he did multiple shadow clones with Rasengan. Also because of the half he received, he could naturally learn Chakra control (thus how to use Rasengan with one hand).

Also, chapter 642, sage mode.

Answer (score -1):

In *Naruto Shippuden the Movie: The Will of Fire*, all of Naruto's clones are able to create the Rasengan independently (using two hands, granted, but independently).

Answer (score -2):

He uses it in the alleyway after he tells Tsunade about his dream. Technically he uses two hands but doesn't use a shadow clone. So I guess he can do it either way but decides to use a clone.

Answer (score -2):

It was in *Naruto Shippuden* when he was caught in an illusion and almost pummeled Kiba.

Answer (score -3):

He did it in episode 100 when he had the vision of Sasuke and Orochimaru and ran at him with the Rasengan.